# Pass arguments to a delayed function with Haxe

Tags: timer, arguments, delay, haxe

Do you know if there is an easy way to pass some arguments to a function called via

```
haxe.Timer.delay(func, delay);
```

By "easy" I mean without creating any custom timer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`bind()`](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-function-bindings.html) for this. For example, if you want to call `someFunction("abc")`:

```
haxe.Timer.delay(someFunction.bind("abc"), 1000); // 1s
```

Prior to Haxe 3, you could use [`callback`](http://old.haxe.org/ref/callback):

```
haxe.Timer.delay(callback(someFunction,"abc"), 1000); // 1s
```

Answer (score 4):

Everything can be achieved with an extra level of indirection :-)

It seems like you need a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) whose only job is to call the other function with arguments.

Something like this (untested):

```
haxe.Timer.delay(function () {
    func(arg1, arg2);
}, delay);
```

Comment: Cameron, the only problem with that is it will treat the function as a anonymous function and remove all context. Depending on your implementation this can be a problem.

Comment: @user: You're right, but in more recent versions of HaXe I believe the closure captures the full context (`this` and all).

Comment: As of today, `delay` in in milliseconds (eg. `1000` produces a one second delay).